# responsive design resize problem - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```dart
Widget myPost(double screenH, BuildContext context, double screenW) {
    String sampleSrc =
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1475924156734-496f6cac6ec1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80";
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: screenW * 0.1),
            height: screenH * 0.1,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
              child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        const CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 30,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: screenW * 0.01,
                        ),
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            const Text(
                              "QWE QWE",
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  "27 min",
                                ),
                                const Icon(
                                  Icons.enhanced_encryption_sharp,
                                  size: 12,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const Icon(Icons.more_vert_sharp),
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
          ReadMoreText(
            "text" * 800,
            trimCollapsedText: "Read More...",
            trimExpandedText: "Read less",
            trimLines: 3,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            trimMode: TrimMode.Line,
            moreStyle: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
            lessStyle: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints.loose(Size.fromHeight(screenH * 0.5)),
              child: Image.network(
                sampleSrc,
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                width: double.infinity,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

My design

[image]

I'm using the [responsive_framework](https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_framework) package, but when I reduce the height, all the widgets  resizing, and I get overflows. The design I'm trying to make is like the following GIF the design that I want

[image]

Just like in responsive sites, I want the widgets to be fixed and only scrollable, no matter how much the height decreases.
Any trick or document to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overall height on shrink is greater than `height: screenH * 0.1,` you can include extra   pixels like `height: 10+ (screenH * 0.1)` But you can just include fixed height here. Like on item, you can choose minimum fixed height like 64, and you don't to have to worry about making larger. You can also check your attached GIF row height doesn't change.

Second option is wrapping `Text` with `FittedBox` widget, or using [`auto_size_text`](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text).